# How to upload a local excel file to my website to do calculations (NOT user input)?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, file-io

I am developing a web based database similar to ERI or CompAnalyst and I have various excel files that need to be read by my website so I can do calculations and present the data to the user. How would I go about uploading my files to the website.

Everything online that I have found just suggests the "input" html element, but that is completely misunderstanding the question. I don't want the user to upload the excel file, I want to have the excel files preloaded, so the user can apply filters to query specific data that is calculated on event of filter changes, NOT an upload of a file. I am using SheetJS to have JavaScript be able to read the excel file, so once the file is uploaded it isn't a problem.

I've tried using an HTML "link" element to declare a path to my excel file, but unlike the "input" element, it doesn't see like I can call `document.getElementById('excel-file').files` on a "link" element.

I have also tried just uploading it straight to JavaScript but then I get this error:
"Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
Which I understand is because of security reasons.

The crux of the question is, how do I get my local excel file to be represented as a File object in JavaScript, without using an event listener from an HTML "input" element?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.